# Phoenix Ecto how to handle NoResultsError

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix JSON API I am getting an Ecto NoResultsError when I request an object that doesn't exist in the database.

I want my JSON API to return a null along with a 404 error.

How would I do this?

Currently I pretty much have a default generated html controller/views etc.  I have modified the controller like this:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  my_model = Repo.get!(MyModel, id)
  case get_format(conn) do
    "json" ->
      render(conn, my_model: my_model)
    _ ->
      render(conn, "show.html", my_model: my_model)
  end
end
```

along with the view:

```
defmodule MyProject.MyModelView do
  use Laired.Web, :view

  def render("show.json", %{my_model: my_model}) do
    my_model
  end
end
```

Related:

[Setting up custom response for exception in Phoenix Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536979/setting-up-custom-response-for-exception-in-phoenix-application)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `get` instead of `get!` and handle the logic when it returns `nil`:

```
def show(conn,%{"id" => id}) do
  case Repo.get(MyModel, id) do
    nil -> # return null and 404 
    record -> # do something with record        
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Can catch the error using `try, rescue` as well

```
def show(conn,%{"id" => id}) do
    try do
      result =
        Repo.get!(MyModel, id)

      {:ok, result}
    rescue
      Ecto.NoResultsError ->
        {:error, :not_found, "No result found"}
    end
end
```

Comment: hmm. it was my understanding that exception control flow is generally bad in Elixir and more relegated to OO languages